# Can't get Eclipse Photo 2018 to run from the Terminal - OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: Ignoring option MaxPermSize; support was removed in 8.0

Tags: java, eclipse, ubuntu

Good day,

Every time I try to run Eclipse (using command line: eclipse) from the terminal on Ubuntu 18.04 I get the following message in the terminal and Eclipse doesn't lauch:

'OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: Ignoring option MaxPermSize; support was removed in 8.0'

Simultaneously, an eclipse window pops-up saying:

'An error has occured. See the log file /home...'

When I double click on the eclipse icon (/home/eclipse/java-photon/eclipse), the program launches successfully.

Eclipse info :

Eclipse IDE for Java Developers
Version: Photon Release (4.8.0)

I have searched for this online but I cannot understand the answers given. If you have an answer or require more specific information, could you please formulate it exhaustively for a beginner. Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Well what does it say in the log file? The message you have shown us is just a warning and won't stop Eclipse from running.

Comment: There might be relative paths in the `eclipse.ini` file (assuming in the terminal you didn't start Eclipse in the Eclipse installation directory). So please, in addition to the log file, add also the content of the `eclipse.ini` file to your question.